# What's the equivalent of JTDS properties in Microsoft JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds, mssql-jdbc

I am changing my JTDS connection to Microsoft JDBC, and I see some properties that exist on http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html that do no exist in Microsoft JDBC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017. Specifically, I am wondering about the equivalent properties in MS JDBC of:

- domain
- namedPipe
- useNTLMv2

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server does not support those options. It only supports

- TCP/IP (not named pipes), and
- native Windows authentication (via sqljdbc_auth.dll) or Kerberos for SQL Server "Windows authentication" (not NTLM).